# ssh connection hangs when looking up a SERVFAIL domain

Tags: ssh-tunneling, socks

Scenario: I am browsing the internet through an `ssh -D` port-forwarding tunnel, both browsing (http, https, ...) connections and domain lookup queries are done using this `SOCKS 5` local proxy.

The problem happens when I click a link to a domain that has a problem with its nameservers, at this point the ssh connection just stalls, all sockets using this proxy are paused, even the interactive shell session (ssh connection) is paused for about half a minute.

Any idea on how to solve this issue (while still using the ssh connection to resolve the domain names)?

Commands below are executed on the server, with an example domain that has this issue.

```
aularon ~ $  time dig kjdecor.com ANY

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> kjdecor.com ANY
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

real    0m21.207s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.009s
aularon ~ $  time nslookup kjdecor.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached


real    0m21.095s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Comment: I can reproduce. That's quite bad. You may want to raise the issue on their [mailing list](http://www.openssh.com/list.html)